# What is the best way to write event handler in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, arrow-functions

I had read the article about [handle events in react with arrow functions](https://medium.com/@machnicki/handle-events-in-react-with-arrow-functions-ede88184bbb). And the final way in that article is not likely the best because of re-render issue.

e.g.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  handleSelect = i => e => {
    console.log(i)
  }

  render() {
    return {this.state.language.map(item, i) => (
      <ListItem 
        ...
        onPress={this.handleSelect(i)}  // re-render sub component every time the Example render() because of the annoymous function
      />
    )}
    
  }
}
```

I wonder which way is the best to write event handler in React?

Comment: "Best" is a very ambiguous term. Please clarify.

Comment: May be a "recommended" way to most case.

Answer (score 4):

In order to get the best performance out of React, you need to minimize the number of objects that are being created during renders. And as a reminder a function declaration (e.g. `function myFunc` or `const func = () => {}`) creates an object.

---

I would say your code has an *unsolvable* issue because you're creating a new instance of the inner function when `handleSelect` is invoked:

```
handleSelect = i => e => {
  console.log(i)
}
```

I'll rewrite this using the `function` notation because it's a bit more clear what happening (but I prefer arrow functions in practice):

```
handleSelect = function (i) {
  return function (e) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

The issue here is the *with each render* when you invoke `handleSelect` *it creates a brand new inner function* (i.e. `function (e) {/* ... */}`).

---

I mentioned that your code has an *unsolvable* issue because there is no way to split up your curried `handleSelect` function because you're passing the index `i` that's *created inside the render function*. Because that state doesn't exist anywhere else, you have to create a new function to close-over it every time and that's okay.

I would even refactor your code like so:

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  // as @RickJolly mentioned, this method doesn't have to be arrow
  handleSelect (i) {
    console.log(i)
  }

  render() {
    return {this.state.language.map(item, i) => (
      <ListItem 
        ...
        onPress={() => this.handleSelect(i)}
    )}

  }
}
```

If you *have to* create a new function every time, then you might as well inline it vs returning a function. That's preference though.

---

*Edit*

As @RickJolly mentioned, if your method doesn't use `this` then it shouldn't be an arrow function.

From his comment:

> since you're calling `() => this.handleSelect(i)` via an arrow function, `this` is bound to the `this` of the enclosing context [which is the class pointer]

Comment: Minor correction on the refactored example: `onPress={() => this.handleSelect(i)}`. Also then `handleSelect` doesn't need to be an arrow function: `handleSelect(i) {...`.

Comment: Thanks. Yep and since you're calling `() => this.handleSelect(i)` via an arrow function, `this` is bound to the function and you can use `this` within. e.g. `handleSelect(i) { this.setState({...}) }`.

Comment: Sorry for my sloppy language though. Arrow functions don't have their own `this`, and they use the `this` of the enclosing context, which is the component's `this` in this case.